# Getting error "Tomcat was unable to start within 45 seconds."

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, tomcat

I am getting an error while running apache tomcat server in ecllipse  and the error description is"Server apache-tomcat-7.0.54 at localhost was unable to start within 45 seconds. If the server requires more time, try increasing the timeout in the server editor".
After getting this message i have increased the time for server to start but the same message i am getting again.

Console prints error is

```
Jun 23, 2014 11:05:20 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property   'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:example' did not find a matching property.
Jun 23, 2014 11:05:20 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jun 23, 2014 11:05:20 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jun 23, 2014 11:05:20 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 868 ms
Jun 23, 2014 11:05:20 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jun 23, 2014 11:05:20 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.54
Jun 23, 2014 11:05:21 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jun 23, 2014 11:05:21 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jun 23, 2014 11:05:21 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 458 ms
```

Comment: check server logs for detailed error message

Comment: Changing start time from 45 seconds to 10 min works for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eclipse has a timeout for starting and stopping Tomcat. You can change it, by opening 'Servers' view, double clicking the server name. As I can see form your logs your server did start in 458ms. But this problem might also be caused by components running lazily after server startup, f.e. servlets having a load-on-startup value greater than 0.

First check if your server really starts up completly. This is when the green 'play' icon ('Start server') turns into a red 'stop' icon and the message 'starting server...' dissapears in the 'Progress' view. If that is not working increase the startup time, as mentioned before. If even that is not working check your servlets for endless slopes or connection attempts to a webservice or a database.